# Getting Google Maps API to display points

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/31b2tbpu/2/

But the map is not displaying?

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 16,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.51367, -0.12981),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: [Your `map` div doesn't have a size](https://jsfiddle.net/31b2tbpu/4/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the *`height`* and *`width`* of the `map` div. See the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31b2tbpu/3/)

In the CSS section, add the following code:

```
#map{
  height:400px;
  width:100%;
}
```